# Какие корни у слов "приграничная" и "располагающаяся"?

Tags: словообразование, морфемика, части, учебное-задание, морфология

Какой корень у слова "располагающаяся"?

**рас** - приставка 
**полаг** - корень (или **по-** тоже приставка, а **-лаг-** корень???)
**а** - суффикс 
**ющ** - суффикс
**ая** - окончание 
**-ся** - суффикс

Подскажите, пожалуйста!

Ведь цепочка образования слова: 
*располагающаяся - располагающая - располагать - полагать*, верно?

и так же в слове "приграничная"

**при** - приставка 
**гранич** - корень (или гран ???) 
**н** - суффикс
**ая** - окончание

Цепочка: *приграничная - граничить - граница...* Слово "грань" не будет являться продолжением цепочки?

буду благодарна за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё верно.

**рас/полаг/а/ющ/ая/ся**
**полаг** - связанный корень.

**при/гранич/н/ая**
**грань** - историч. корень.

Comment: http://udarenieru.ru/index.php?word=on&morph_word=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C

просто этот сайт трактует "по" как еще одну приставку...

Comment: В школьном словаре Текучёва - наш с Вами вариант, у Тихонова - ВВвВ школном словаре Тихонова наш с Вами вариант. У Тихонова корень располаг-
(прямо сейчас). 
Людмила

Comment: спасибо большое за помощь!

Comment: Панов и Текучев (Школьный грамматико-орфографический словарь русского языка. 1985) -- корень "лаг".

Тихонов (Словарь-справочник по русскому языку. 1997) -- корень "лаг".

Тихонов в Сети -- корень "лаг" (https://slovari.yandex.ru/~%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F/ )

Comment: Простите, но в словарях в сети много ошибок. Передо мной Панов-Текучёв 1991г. бумажный вариант, -полаг- Тихонов бумажный, но более раннего выпуска -располаг

Comment: Возможно, это разный взгляд на связанные корни, кто-то их выделяет вместе в приставкой, а кто-то отдельно.

Comment: Мы не знаем, какого взгляда придерживается данный преподаватель

Answer (score 0):

Вот скринчик "Школьного словообразовательного словаря" Тихонова А.Н. 1991г.

[image]

Сам совсем не филолог, просто мне тоже интересно. :)

Comment: Это словообразовательный словарь, а не морфемный, там просто указана нечленимая основа."располож".Если рассуждать логически, то "полагать" в этом значении уже не употребляется, только "положить", но ведь расположиться и располагаться, положить однокоренные,значит, приставка точно выделяется, а вот "ложить" в литературном языке теперь слова нет, корень связанный,и пошли расхождения. Кто-то выделяет корень лож/лаг, а кто-то полож/полаг. Чьего мнения придерживается учитель - не знаю.

Comment: Мнение учителя должно быть таким же, какое поддерживают составители ЕГЭ и ЦТ.